# Upper bound for a gamma function

Tags: inequality, special-functions

Let $n \in N$. How to find a non-asymptotic upper bound for $\Gamma(n)$ and $\Gamma(\frac n2+1)$?

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?aid=5898896)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 6.5.1 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6) gives a reasonably tight bound except for very small n. I suppose section 5.11 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11) also could be unpacked to yield some upper bounds, depending on exactly what you're looking for. (I assume you know that for integer n, $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.)

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to get some refference as a book.